# Updating material-ui 3.9.3 to 4.2.1 issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have updated my package.json file to be... and run npm install but my package-lock.json file is still showing material-ui 3.9.3...

````
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.0.0",

"@material-ui/core": {
      "version": "3.9.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@material-ui/core/-/core-3.9.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-REIj62+zEvTgI/C//YL4fZxrCVIySygmpZglsu/Nl5jPqy3CDjZv1F9ubBYorHqmRgeVPh64EghMMWqk4egmfg==",
      "requires": {```

Removed all package-lock.json code and rerun npm install.

I have npm install @material-ui/core and then run npm install still i am getting 3.9.3

I need to create a component using the slider and am unable to find module Slider in /core

Is there a reason why I am unable to get this project to update? I am running Reactjs 16.8.6
````

Comment: Have you tried clearing your npm cache?

Comment: I did npm cache clean --force

Comment: ```"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "async-retry": "^1.2.3",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.30",
    "aws-amplify-react": "^2.3.8",
    "d3": "^5.9.2",

  },```

Comment: OMG My callstack was not saving the files for some reason!( Ughh Solved***